# How to add an item to the repository without loading the item's Parent and siblings into memory

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

EntityFramework, code first solution.

My 'repository'

```
public abstract class BaseEfDataRepository : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

`Account` is

```
public virtual List<User> Users { get; private set; }
```

How can I add a new `User` to an `Account`, using Linq-To-Entities, without loading the entire `Account` object, or at least without loading the entire `Users` set from it.

I usually do it as:

```
var account = context.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(acc => acc.Id == accountId);
account.Users.Add(newUser);
context.Save();
```

but I've noticed that this loads the entire set into memory, which I want to avoid.

Is it possible? What are my options? I can think of:
Expose the `Users` in `DbContext` and add the user from there. But this would cause all other kind of problems for me.

Any other options?

Comment: Your context evidently knows `User` as a mapped class. I don't understand what *kind of problems* you'd face by adding an `IDbSet<User>` to it. The easiest way would be to add users and setting their `AccountId`s if they've got that property.

Comment: @GertArnold, well, for one, the `AccountId` property has a private setter and I want it to stay that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the `Account`'s id value, you can create a *stub entity* and add the `User` to its `Users` collection:

```
var acc = new Account { Id = accountId };
context.Accounts.Attach(acc);
acc.Users.Add(newUser);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Since `Account.Users` has a private setter, I assume you initialize the collection in the constructor.

Comment: I am actually going with your other solution (I made the setter of the `AccountId` `internal`), but I am having an issue. The `AccountId` is only half of the composite key, the other half is `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`. Now when I set the `AccountId` I am getting _A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a corresponding primary key value does not exist_ error.