# EF6 with Entity Framework Plus: Adding object from memory cache to collection of Entities then saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

I'm using EF Plus's caching functionality to cache frequently-used immutable lookup entities in memory.

All of the cached entity types can be part of some parent entity's collection (ie: if I have a collection of entities of type Product in the cache, I should be able to add any of them to a proxied Order entity's Products collection to say, "this Order is comprised of these Products")

However, when I add one of the cached items to a "live" entity's contained collection, I get the following exception:

```
{"The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects."}
```

How do I fix this?  Autofac is registered to create an InstancePerRequest() of the context so I am wondering if the cached entity is holding on to the old DbContext. I would have thought EFPlus would have detached them by default, however.

What is best practice for caching lookup entities that can be added to an entity's collection properties?

Edit: I did notice this: https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/27335291/how-to-detach-entity-from-context-when-you-no-longer-have-a-context-reference

Edit 2: Now I have disabled proxy creation temporarily, but it's still not working. Here's the code I've got which is the *only* method to read from the cache (ignore the fact I'm returning an IQueryable here, I know its an anti-pattern and it'll get fixed later)

```
    public async Task<IQueryable<TEntity>> AsQueryable()
    {
        var proxyCreationEnabled = _context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled;
        try
        {
            _context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var unproxiedEntities = (await _dbSet.FromCacheAsync(_cacheKey)).AsQueryable();
            return unproxiedEntities;
        }
        finally
        {
            _context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = proxyCreationEnabled;
        }
    }
```

When I add a cached entry to a live proxied object's collection, like so:

```
var otherIntervention = await _otherInterventionRepository.GetByIdAsync(otherInterventionId); // reads the cache
toBeSaved.OtherInterventions.Add(otherIntervention);
```

Now nothing happens...  and yes, otherInterventionId is the primary key of the entity I want to add.

Here's what else I've tried: I've tried adding a new OtherIntervention object with just the Id field set, but I get validation errors as a [Required] Description field is missing. If I could just add a new object to the OtherInterventions collection, with the ID field set to that of the EXISTING lookup record, I'd be happy. I really don't want to create an overload of GetByIdAsync which skips the cache and loads from context directly - then what's the point of the cache?

Edit 3:
Looks like I'm going to have to Attach the object from the cache to the context, which I don't currently have access to (its abstracted behind a repository)

[How to add an item to the repository without loading the item's Parent and siblings into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41782052/how-to-add-an-item-to-the-repository-without-loading-the-items-parent-and-sibli)

Edit 4:
Attaching an object from the cache gives me an error that an object of the same type with the same Id already exists!

I'm giving up for now. Its taking too long to fix.

If anyone knows any fix, please share. Thanks.

Comment: *but I can't globally disable proxy creation.* -- Why not?

Comment: Have updated with latest research into issue.